# Cassandra UDT: error: unpack requires a string argument of length 4

Tags: c#, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Using [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.5.469 | DSE 4.7.0 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]
and the C# 2.5 driver, **I'm trying to represent user settings as a UDT**.

The following is defined in a *.cql script:

```
CREATE TYPE GeneralSettings (
    last_changed        timestamp,
    last_tokaned        timestamp,
    tokan               text,
    emails              list<text>,
);

CREATE TABLE users (
    id                  timeuuid,
    name                text,
    general_settings    frozen<GeneralSettings>,

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The following is defined in my C# code:

```
public class UserGeneralSettings
{
    public DateTimeOffset? LastChanged { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? LastTokened { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Emails { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
session.UserDefinedTypes.Define(
            UdtMap.For<UserGeneralSettings>().Map(s => s.LastChanged, "last_changed")
                                             .Map(s => s.LastTokened, "last_tokaned")
                                             .Map(s => s.Token, "tokan")
                                             .Map(s => s.Emails, "emails")
        );
```

---

```
For<User>()
        .TableName("users")
        .PartitionKey(e => e.Id)
        .Column(e => e.Id, cm => cm.WithName("id"))
        .Column(e => e.Name, cm => cm.WithName("name"))
        .Column(e => e.GeneralSettings, cm => cm.WithName("general_settings"));
```

I'm trying to insert the following data as a new user record, using the [IMapper](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/2.5/csharp-driver/reference/mapperComponent.html) interface:

```
newUser.GeneralSettings = new UserGeneralSettings
        {
            Emails = new [] { "test@provider.com" },
            LastChanged = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
            LastTokened = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
            Token = "abcd-efg-hijk-lmnop-qrst-uvw-xyz",
        };
```

But even though the insertion goes smoothly, it looks like it is corrupting my users table because I can't select anything from that table using cqlsh.
The error that I'm getting is:

*Traceback (most recent call last):*

*File "/usr/share/dse/resources/cassandra/bin/cqlsh", line 1056, in perform_simple_statement rows = self.session.execute(statement, trace=self.tracing_enabled)*

*File "/usr/share/dse/resources/cassandra/bin/../lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-2.5.1.zip/cassandra-driver-2.5.1/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1405, in execute result = future.result(timeout)*

*File "/usr/share/dse/resources/cassandra/bin/../lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-2.5.1.zip/cassandra-driver-2.5.1/cassandra/cluster.py", line 2976, in result raise self._final_exception*

***error: unpack requires a string argument of length 4***

Does anyone know what causes this error? 
Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds a lot like [CASSANDRA-7656](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7656).  Although, that was supposed to have been fixed in one of the later 2.1 release candidates.  Are any of the values you are inserting null?

My theory as to what is happening here, is that Cassandra matches a `timestamp` with a C# `DateTimeOffset`.  And that is ***not*** the same as a `DateTimeOffset?` (nullable).

Change your `UserGeneralSettings` class to use `DateTimeOffset` for your timesstamps and not a nullable type (`DateTimeOffset?`).  Then truncate your table and try your insert again.